# Difference between hist and imhist in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram, entropy

What is the difference between `hist` and `imhist` functions in Matlab? I have a matrix of color levels values loaded from image with `imread` and need to count entropy value of the image using histogram.
When using `imhist` the resulting matrix contains zeros in all places except the last one (lower-right) which contains some high value number (few thousands or so).
Because that output seems to be wrong, I have tried to use hist instead of `imhist` and the resulting values are much better, the matrix is fulfilled with correct-looking values instead of zeros.
However, according to the docs, `imhist` should be better in this case and `hist` should give weird results..
Unfortunately I am not good at Matlab, so I can not provide you with better problem description. I can add some other information in the future, though.

So I will try to better explain my problem..I have an image, for which I should count entropy and few other values (how much bytes it will take to save that image,..). I wrote this function and it works pretty well

```
 function [entropy, bytes_image, bytes_coding] = entropy_single_pixels(im)

im = double(im);

histg = hist(im);

histg(histg==0) = [];
nzhist = histg ./ numel(im);
entropy = -sum(nzhist.*log2(nzhist));

bytes_image = (entropy*(numel(im))/8);

bytes_coding = 2*numel(unique(im));

fprintf('ENTROPY_VALUE:%s\n',num2str(entropy));
fprintf('BYTES_IMAGE:%s\n',num2str(bytes_image));
fprintf('BYTES_CODING:%s\n',num2str(bytes_coding));
end
```

Then I have to count the same, but I have to make "pairs" from pixels which are below each other. So I have only half the rows and the same count of columns. I need to express every unique pixel pair as a different number, so I multiplied the first one by 1000 and added the second one to it... Subsequently I need to actually apply the same function as in the first example, but that is the time, when I am getting weird numbers from the `imhist` function. When using hist, it seems to be OK, but I really don't think that behavior is correct, so that must be my error somewhere. I actually understand pretty good, to what I want to do, or at least I hope so, but unfortunately Matlab makes all that kind of hard for me :)

Comment: See: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/64304

Comment: I have altered my question, actually the link you provided didnt help me that much. I have searched the web before, also found that thread, but I am still stucked there:/

Comment: If you read the thread carefully it confirms that you need to use `imhist`, not `hist`, since the former operates on 2D images (i.e. matrices), whereas the latter only operates on vectors.

Comment: ok..so when I use reshape to convert the pixel matrix to one row vector, hist function should work?

Comment: That might work, but it would be inefficient and pointless - why not just use `imhist` in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hist- compute histogram(count number of occurance of each pixel) in color image.........

imhist- compute histogram in two dimensional image.

Answer (score 1):

Use `im2double` instead of `double` if you want to use `imhist`. The `imhist` function expects double or single-precision data to be in the [0,1] data range, which is why you see everything in the last bin of the histogram.